# Ideal of an affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a basic problem. I want to calculate the coordinate Ring of a variety, but I can not calculate the ideal related to the variety.
For example I don't know how can I find the ideal for this variety :
$$
\{ (t^2, t^3) ~\mid~  t \in\Bbb C\}.
$$
Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

With the tools of differential geometry, you can check the origin is a cuspidal point, with the $x$-axis as a tangent.

You can eliminate $t$ to show the points of the curve satisfy the equation $y^2=x^3$.

Conversely, to show all points of the curve $y^2=x^3$, you can consider the intersections of a variable line through the origin: $y=tx$, which cuts the curve in the origin (double intersection) and a third point. Check this third point has the required parameterisation w.r.t. $t$.